# Tkinterで画像が反映されない

Tags: python, tkinter

#### 困ってること

Tkinterを使用してpythonでソフトを作ろうとしているのですが、コードを打っても画像が表示されません。
ちゃんとpyファイルと画像ファイルを同じフォルダに入れて、画像ファイル名を選択しています。

PhotoImageやbuttonだけでなくアイコンも反映されてないので、多分そもそも画像ファイル自体が無理っぽいです。

#### 試したこと

・PCの再起動
・pythonのアンインストール＆再インストール
・cmdで `python -V` と打ち、バージョンが出ることの確認
・別画像で試す
・ファイルを別の場所に移す

*初心者なもので解決法が全く分からず困っています。親切な方回答お願いします。

[image: 実際のコード]

Comment: この記事が同じライブラリを使っているので参考にしてみてはどうでしょう？ [tkinterで画像を表示させる](https://betashort-lab.com/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0/python/tkinter%E3%81%A7%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/) それからソースコードはテキストで提示しましょう。[スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Answer (score 1):

手元の環境では正常に画像が表示されました。
実行環境のアクティブディレクトリが画像のファイルパスと異なるのかもしれません。

下記のようなコードを実行して表示されるパスにファイルが配置されているかをご確認ください。

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath('icon.ico')) # アイコンを取りに行く時のフルパス
```

---

表示されるパスにファイルが配置されていない場合は、以下のような対処法をご検討ください。

- 出てきたパスにファイルを配置する(推奨)
  `C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\ドキュメント\MyPython\Tkinter講座\icon.ico` のファイルを
  `C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\ドキュメント\MyPython\icon.ico` に移動します。
- [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)で作業ディレクトリを移動する
  コードの3行目あたりに`import os`と`os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\ドキュメント\MyPython\Tkinter講座")`を追記します。
- 作業ディレクトリを変更する
  VS Codeを使っていて、『ターミナル』からPowerShell実行をしているならば
  『ターミナル』の`PS C:\(中略)\MyPython>`の後ろに`cd C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\ドキュメント\MyPython\Tkinter講座`と記述してEnterキーを押します。
  その後にpythonの実行コマンドを入力します。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます！
確認したところ上記のコードを打つと「C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\ドキュメント\MyPython\icon.ico」と出るのですが、実際には「"C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\ドキュメント\MyPython\Tkinter講座\icon.ico"」なのでパスが違うことがわかりました

この場合どうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 対応方法を回答に追記しました。

Comment: 推奨された方法を実行したところアイコンとpng画像の表示はされるようになりました
しかしjpeg画像の表示だけされません。pillowというライブラリを読み込み教材通りにコードも書いているのですがウィンドウに表示されません

コードにエラーも出ていないのですが、これはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 実際のコードです
import tkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Image practice!')
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
root.geometry('550x550')
root.resizable(0, 0)

image_1 = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='sukahu.png')
label_1 = tkinter.Label(root, image=image_1)
label_1.pack()

button_1 = tkinter.Button(root ,image=image_1)
button_1.pack()

image_by_pillow = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('yama.jpeg'))
label_by_pillow = tkinter.Label(root, image=image_by_pillow)
label_by_pillow.pack()


root.mainloop()

Comment: コメントではなく質問への追記をお願いします。